# Scrapy code reading from multiple urls and then writing results in final csv

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I need to extract data from the script tag of multiple urls with Regex. I've managed to implement a code that does half of the job. I have a csv file(`'links.csv '`) that contains all the urls I'll need to scrape. I managed to read the csv and store all the urls in the variable named `'start_urls'`. My problem is that I need a way to read the urls from `'start_urls'` one at a time and execute the next part of my code. 
When I execute my code in the terminal I receive 2 errors:

1.ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
2. TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list

How can I fix my code? I am a beginner in Scrapy, but I really need this script to work... Thank you in advance!

Here are some examples of urls I stored in the initial csv('links.csv'):

```
"https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-note8/"
"https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-s8/"
"https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-s9/"
```

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import csv
import re

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('links.csv','r') as csvf:
            for url in csvf:
                yield scrapy.Request(url.strip())

    def parse(self, response):
        source = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS')]/text()").extract()[0]
        def get_values(parameter, script):
            return re.findall('%s = "(.*)"' % parameter, script)[0]

        with open('baza.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Category', 'Type', 'SK']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for pvi_subtype_name,pathIndicator.depth_5,model_name in zip(source):
                writer.writerow({'Category': get_values("pvi_subtype_name", source), 'Type': get_values("pathIndicator.depth_5", source), 'SK': get_values("model_name", source)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the following method to spider:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('links.csv','r') as csvf:
        for url in csvf:
            yield scrapy.Request(url.strip())
```

And remove previous `with...` block from code.

Comment: Thank you very much @mizhgun ! I've edited the code with your suggestion and run it. I still have 2 errors. I think they appear in that part that write in the final csv file ('baza.csv') but I don't really know how to modify it. Errors are: 1. for pvi_subtype_name,pathIndicator.depth_5,model_name in zip(source):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)  AND 2. source = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS')]/text()").extract()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range.     I edited my code above too. Thank you again!